# Char, Malloc, and Struct Arrays

Tags: arrays, struct, char, malloc

Im still learning C and I have a question regarding char arrays, malloc and structures. I have the following structure.

Function prototype

```
typedef struct example1{
 char *name[20];
 int ex_id;
 int count;
}example;
```

In main.c

```
example *info;
info=(example *)malloc(sizeof(example));
info->name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

printf("Enter ID: ");
scanf("%d", &info[info->count].ex_id);

printf("Enter Name of ID: ");
scanf("%s", info->name[info->count];
getchar();
```

So my problem is I can't seem to malloc char *name[20] inside my structure. What I want to do with this variable is dynamically store the number of names with a fix strength length of 20 characters. So basically what I want to store is something like this.

info->name[0]="name1";

info->name[1]="name2";

etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *name[20];` this is an array of char*.  But

```
info->name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

You are allocating just one byte that the char* array elements point to. Allocate 20 bytes for each of the index, as you mentioned:

```
for (i=0;i<20;i++) 
{
    info->name[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20); 
}
```

Also, you are treating your struct pointer `info` as an array:

```
scanf("%d", &info[info->count].ex_id);
```

You can't do this, because: `info->count` is not initialized & holds garbage value.
And, you have allocated space for just one object of your struct by:

```
info=(example *)malloc(sizeof(example));
```

which makes `&info[info->count]` valid only when `info->count`=0, for the rest you have not allocated any space.

Comment: Thank you broken foot that worked out really well. I forgot I also needed to allocate space.

Comment: Glad could help. Traditionally you up-vote when you like an ans. :)